# Cast float to decimal in C#. Why is (decimal)0.1F == 0.1M not false because of rounding?

Tags: c#, floating-point, rounding-error

If I evaluate the following in C#, it yields true:

```
(decimal)0.1F == 0.1M
```

Why doesn't the conversion to float and back to decimal introduce any rounding errors?

Comment: (decimal)somethingF will not always be equal to somethingM - due to how floating point works. That doesn't mean, however, that they will **never** be equal.

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . Why does this matter to you?

Comment: @mjwills Since 0.1 in floating-point is really 0.100000001490116119384765625, I expected them to be unequal.

Comment: Seems like that would depend on the level of precision being used. Also, when I type `.1F` into the immediate window, the result is `0.1`. The number only changes after I do `.1F * 1.0`.

Comment: @mjwills I have numbers stored as decimals and wanted to know how they behave if I convert them to doubles, use Math.Pow, and then convert them back.

Comment: @Aae Then why are you using floats, and not doubles?

Comment: @Servy I expected the concept to be the same. I get the same result if I write (decimal)0.1D == 0.1M.

Comment: Also, how they behave for *one single value* is not going to be representative of how they behave for arbitrary values.

Comment: Resharper reports that `((decimal) 0.1F == 0.1M)` "Expression is always true".  I tried introducing some float variables (one, ten, and then oneDivTen) and it still evaluates true.  Go figure.  It's still never a good idea to rely on the truthiness of floating point equality comparisons

Comment: @RufusL I can also do `(decimal)0.100000009F == 0.1M` and get `true`.

Comment: @Servy Maybe not. This is kind of an experiment that falsified a hypothesis I had about the behavior.

Comment: This is a dead-end question, i mean, you could be here all day, why does this work and not that. The specs and the CLR does the best it can not to introduce errors, in short some of these results aren't obvious. However, what you need to be aware of is that there are many situations in which they cannot and will not save you. So when doing conversions and planning your code, be mindful of the actual limitations of floating point values. don't rely on these simplistic tests

Comment: The C# compiler isn't very different from most other curly-brace language compilers, it aggressively tries to evaluate expressions at compile-time.  A *const-expression* is an important syntactical construct in those languages.  After it is done with it, assuming it appears in an if-statement, it devolves into `if (true)`.  Whether it should do so for floating point math is a highly debatable issue, given that evaluation results depend so much on the execution environment.  But that's what they decided.  The Golden Rule remains, never use == to compare floating point values.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine((decimal)0.1F);` <- woah whats going on here,  `Console.WriteLine((decimal)(double)0.1F);` <-- example of asserting your authority

Comment: In summary, the answer of `why does this code work?` is that nothing in the spec says that it _mustn't_ work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of the observed behavior is that Microsoft’s C# implementation converts `float` to `decimal` using only seven decimal digits.

Microsoft’s implementation of C# uses .NET. When .NET converts a single-precision floating-point number to decimal, [it produces at most seven significant digits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todecimal?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Convert_ToDecimal_System_Single_), rounding any residue using round-to-nearest.

The source text `0.1F` becomes the single-precision value 0.100000001490116119384765625. When this is converted to decimal with seven significant digits, the result is exactly 0.1. Thus, in Microsoft’s C#, `(decimal) 0.1F` produces 0.1, so `(decimal) 0.1F == 0.1M` is true.

We can compare this with a non-Microsoft implementation, Mono C#. An online compiler for this is available [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_csharp_online.php). In it, `Console.WriteLine((decimal)0.1F);` prints “0.100000001490116”, and `(decimal)0.1F == 0.1M` evaluates to false. Mono C# appears to produce more than seven digits when converting `float` to `decimal`.

[Microsoft’s C# documentation for explicit conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/explicit-numeric-conversions-table) says “When you convert `float` or `double` to `decimal`, the source value is converted to decimal representation and rounded to the nearest number after the 28th decimal place if required.” I would have interpreted this to mean that the true value of the `float`, 0.100000001490116119384765625, is exactly converted to `decimal` (since it requires fewer than 28 digits), but apparently this is not the case.

We can further confirm this and illustrate what is happening by converting `float` to `double` and then to `decimal`. [Microsoft’s C# converts `double` to `decimal` using 15 significant digits.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todecimal?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Convert_ToDecimal_System_Double_) If we convert `0.1F` to `double`, the value does not change, because `double` can exactly represent each `float` value. So `(double) 0.1F` has exactly the same value as `0.1F`, 0.100000001490116119384765625. However, now, when it is converted to `decimal`, 15 digits are produced. In a Microsoft C# implementation, `Console.WriteLine((decimal)(double) 0.1F);` prints “0.100000001490116”, and `(decimal)(double) 0.1F == 0.1M` evaluates to false.